# How to automatically rewrite c++ code with semantic informations?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-ir

What I want is applying a transform just like `{ {ObjA}.func1() -> {ObjA}.func2() | for all {ObjA} is {SpecClass}}`. That is, transforming all objects of type `SpecClass`'s function call to `A::func1()` to `A::func2()`.

Obviously it needs semantic information to do this. Are there any existing tools to do things like this(, or maybe even more powerful)? Or I need to develop one using Clang-LibTooling or what?

Before transformation:

```cpp
struct A{
    void f();
    void g();
};

struct B{
    void f();
    void g();
};

void foo()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.f();
    b.f();
}
```

After transformation:

```cpp
struct A{
    void f();
    void g();
};

struct B{
    void f();
    void g();
};

void foo()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.g();
    b.f();
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to do.

Comment: Chatgpt perhaps :)

Comment: One example of the transformation is not enough. Please try to define your goal, to describe i English what you want. (And I do not even really get what is transformed into what in your example...) Generally, please try for [ask]. And I think you might enjoy the [tour].

Comment: @Yunnosch did it.

Comment: This looks a runtime problem, you have a container with pointers to `Object`s in it. `Object` may be specialized in different ways and if the object is `SpecClass` call its virtual function. If its a compile time problem, just make a template wrapper to call `Object` function, with a specialization for `SpecClass`.

Comment: Please read up on the keyword "refactoring" and tell how much it is what you want to do. Many IDEs provide (beyond what is described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75457330/7733418 ) some mechanisms to do that largely automatically.

Comment: What you describe looks like search-and-replace or refactoring. I do not get how "semantiv" information comes into it.

Comment: Please provide two [mre]s for before and after the desired change. It will spare you to add infos like "both functions are already defined" piece by piece.... You could also tell a story on how using it (what you are asking for) would be experienced. That story could include "I have a text file with semantic information in the syntax of ... for example .... so that my files (2 code files, 5 header files), change from .... to ... ."

Comment: Probably need to develop your own with Clang libs.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, it's search and replace. But what's different is I want to search not a specific identifier, but "all identifiers that represent a specific class". and do some replacement on statements with it(but not itself).

Comment: Please read up on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and check that we are not looking at one. Maybe you add information on what it is you want to achieve by doing what you are asking about.

Comment: @Yunnosch Did it.

Comment: Sorry, it does not look like you did.

Comment: If you have `PointerToObject->f` do you need it to replace only if the pointer is pointing to an `A` but not if it is pointing to a `B`?

Comment: @Yunnosch No, I want just a static tool/method without the code running. This may be beyond my need.

Comment: FYI, for C there's [Coccinelle](https://coccinelle.gitlabpages.inria.fr/website/), and you could probably find the targets with a tool like [Weggli](https://github.com/weggli-rs/weggli).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I interpret the question correctly (i.e., as applying this on the source code) this is commonly done in IDEs.

E.g., Visual Studio can rename a member function `func1` to `func2` and then all calls `ObjA.func1()` will be changed to `ObjA.func2()`.

If `func2` already exist then:

1. Change `func2` to `func2dummy` - without using refactoring
2. Rename `func1` to `func2` - using refactoring
3. Change `func2` back to `func1` and `func2dummy` back to `func2` - without using refactoring

Other refactoring tool, including ones built on llvm, can likely do the same.

Comment: Typo "rectoring"/"refactoring"? In that case my comment on the question is redundant.

Comment: What I mean is, the `func1` and `func2` all already exist.

Comment: @zclll And how does that change what you want to do? How does it mean that this does not help?

Comment: @Yunnosch That means I dont wanna rename `func1` to `func2`, but change the call for all `A::func1` to `A::func2`.

Comment: @zclll: So For your example, comment `A::g` (declaration and definition), rename (using factorisation) `A::f` into `g`, then change manually `A::g` to `A::f` and uncomment first step.